# This my approach to make a superhuman combat sport more fair?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, technique, plot, combat

This isn't really a world-building question. Since I im asking for y'all thoughts on my writing and writing a general.

In the past, I said it would be hard to add an MMA/Boxing weight class type of fairness System to a Metahuman/Mutant fighting combat sport. Because the superpowers are too broad and unique to be put into specific classes. Even among two Gods or two powerful Aliens the power levels can still varied. It's like every Metahuman has their own weight class.

That's the biggest problem with this concept. The versatility of power levels making it hard to give specific classes for Metahuman fighters.

'   .

I made a kinetic energy-absorbing boxing ring. If you are familiar with the X men first class movie or Black Panther Vibranium suit. An X men Villain and The Black Panther suit both can absorb kinetic energy.

So implied the same mechanics and properties of the X men Villain power and BP suit to a Boxing Ring. Yae the Ring matt and ropes can absorb the Kinetic energy of the Meta Fighters. And send it right back to them.

So this way the weaker characters/fighters have a chance at beating much more stronger opponents and winning. For example, Hulk can destroy Daredevil in a fight. But in this ring Daredevil can find a way to trip Hulk and let his face hit the mat and get him knockout on the ground. And the mat absorbed the impact and sent right back at Hulk. And DD wins.

Now the weaker characters' advantage is the same advantage that can be used against them too. This is why I made the ring absorb quadruple times the force of the impact depending on power levels. Meaning the higher the power level and the more powerful a Meta fighter is. The more the ring is going to absorb the impact of the OP fighter and times it by 4. Causing the bigger fighter to get 4 times to increase and the same impact to be sent right back to him/her whenever they fall on the ring mat. It's like the bigger they are the harder they fall concept.

The same kinetic absorption implies to everything else. All sorts of Arenas like Gladiator stadium and MMA cages and octagons from the UFC. Even weapons like chairs and kendo sticks. All absorb kinetic energy and sent it right back at you. And times that force to 4x.

The ring is big enough for weaker Meta fighters to win with Guerrilla War tactics and using the environment to their advantage. Similar to how Batman used the environment to his advantage when he is fighting more powerful opponents like Grundy. So some fights aren't going to be about who is the strongest. Wins the fight. Some fights are going to be win by the Meta Fighters who are the smartest and who also used the better strategy.

?

I don't know if you guys are familiar with Dragon Ball z. But I assume you guys know what Attack Potency means. In Dragon, Ball characters have punches and kicks that can destroy planets and universes. But they limit and control that destructive power and redirect that same destructive power into only one sport. That one sport being the opponent they are trying to kick and punch at the time. So their punches and kicks don't destroy the whole planet or universe. Because they are focusing all that destructive power into one sport.

Now imagine that this ring has the same power as that. The ring can absorb the impact and power levels of the powerful Meta Fighters. But still, manage to contain that's destructive power and redirect it to only the Meta Fighter that falls on the ground.

?

Honestly, it's really hard to bypass/negate pass the fighters with invisibility/invulnerability. An MMA knockout or TKO isn't going to stop them. Hell, a TKO isn't going to stop the Meta Fighters with powerful healing Factors like Wolverine and Deadpool.

Which Is why went the WWE Pro Wrestling pinfall route. You can't knock out an Invulnerable/Invisible fighter or defeat them via a TKO. But at least you can pin them on the ground for at least 3 seconds lol. And defeat them that way.

In conclusion.

That's the way I went about it. So what are your thoughts?

Comment: Engagement with this community will be more effective if you ask questions about writing with the absolute minimum of details describing your world or story. You will get the most benefit and the best answers by distilling your challenge down questions of craft or storytelling.

Comment: So you want me to be vague. So how can I ask questions when people don't have a clue what im talking about? If I said, "how can you write a ring that has a kinetic absorption ring that benefits weaker fighters?" Now, How can people understand my question when I just say this without details. I had to try my best to get my point across without making the question too long right now. And it still sounds a bit vague.

Comment: Questions that revolve around intricate details of story or world building are either ignored or closed. This community seems most effective at helping with question of craft or character development or story telling.  It's not about being vague, but being very precise in your question and supplying the salient details so the community can help you. I think you are wanting help in 'balancing a magic system' which really belongs to WB, but because the question has so many details that is not coming across very clearly.  Keep in mind that I'm trying to help you.

Comment: Ok, I just thought the writing sub also had something to do with critique.as well

Comment: I still think this is going to be more of a WB question, but I suspect you'll need to go virtual somehow to compensate. No matter haw clever you are, you'll still have significant game disbalancing in any system with such different opponents. I've been told the ultimate Marvel universe character as deemed by analysis is Spider Man, but obviously there are many individuals where their special skills allow them to defeat Spider Man specifically and easily. There's no universal way to do it short of a giant points analysis with individuals playing games solo and comparing total scores.

Comment: @BackBack33 Writing critiques are explicitly off-topic here. We do have [a chatroom for them](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115415/beta-reviewers-reviewing), but it's more for stories that you've already written and want feedback on, rather than just ideas that you want feedback on.

Answer (score 1):

When writing about superhuman combat, even sport forms of combat, there are often a number of common assumptions:

1. Powers are not expected to be scientifically accurate.
2. Technology is likewise not expected to be scientifically accurate.
3. Powers will vary widely in both kind and impact.

Rather than try to solve the problem of "fairness" (whatever that is supposed to mean) by convincing the reader (or us) that your author solution is right, simply present your idea in the story, and have the characters argue about it. Or you could present it as a done deal, and don't bother to over explain.

As a personal opinion, and given the nature of superhuman powers, a SPHERE or CUBE shaped arena would likely be better than a traditional boxing style ring, and would offer more potential protection to an erstwhile audience.

Also, something that pushes back with four times the force could easily be used to launch oneself as an attack or dodge, and thus seems easily exploitable to me. Not to mention the potential flubber effect.... Perhaps storing the absorbed energy and using it to power the shield systems might be more effective?

Finally, have you considered an Olympics style competition that includes various combat events, including an unlimited MMA style classification? That way your superhumans could each compete in their own areas of expertise (strength, speed, elements, stealth, etc), or take the risk in the freestyle combat rankings.